# Transparent Authentication with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have implemented my server with Spring 4 and Spring Security 3.2.

I am working with two possible scenarios to authentification, it depends from the user client type, web applications, which authentificate throught html form, and mobile client like Android or iOS.

User mobile application can leave to work with the app losing his authentication in the server when the session expire, in this scenario I am trying to authenticate client through Authenticator header param and one custom EntryPoint which can see like this.

```
public class AuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    @Autowired
    private RestProvider restProvider;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                         AuthenticationException authenticationException) 
            throws IOException, ServletException {

        Device device = (Device) request.getAttribute("device");

        if (device.isNormal()) { // WEB

            response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath()));
        } else { // MOBILE

            DeviceAuth deviceAuth = new DeviceAuth(request.getHeader("Authorization"));

            UserAuthToken userAuthToken = (UserAuthToken) this.restProvider.authenticate(
                    new IncomingToken(
                            deviceAuth.getEmail(),
                            null,
                            "user",
                            deviceAuth.getNode(),
                            deviceAuth.getAuthToken())
            );

            if (userAuthToken != null) {

                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuthToken);
            }

            if (request.getRequestURI() != null) {

                response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(request.getContextPath() + 
                        request.getRequestURI()));
            } else {

                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST, "Not page");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Device class is loaded previusly in the request from one custom Filter which analyze the request to determine the device type.

RestProvider is one of the two application Providers which return UserAuthToken, one custom implementation of UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.

All this work fine, except redirect question, I want to achieve transparent authentication process, namely, when user leave to work with the application, and return to use it after his server session (and authentication) has been destroyed, server identify bad credentials, get authentication header to authenticate and continue with the request transparently to the app.

How I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Answer my question by myself.

Instead of implement AuthenticationEntryPoint, I had implemented BasicAuthenticationFilter with the same logic that can see in my previous post, removing the normal device control, as normal internet explorers not work with BasicAuthentication.

```
public class BasicAuthFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    ...

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
                FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

    ...
    }
}
```

[HERE](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/basic.html) you can read more about BasicAuthentication.